# p:selectOneMenu doesn't scroll

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to put a category list in a `p:selectOneMenu`, but it doesn't scroll the list. Instead it show me the entire list.

Can someone explain me why?

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="categoria"
                 value="#{prodottoController.idcategoria}"
                 dynamic="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{categoriaController.listaCategorie()}"
                   var="item1"
                   itemValue="#{item1.idcategoria}"
                   itemLabel="#{item1.nome}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Tried setting the `height` attribute?

Comment: yes now it works i have put  height in panel style attribute: panelStyle="overflow:scroll;height:150px", Thanks